# Не переведена часть сообщения о readonly-режиме

Tags: дефект, локализация

Первые два предложения переведены, а вот третье тоже надо бы.

> Сайт находится в режиме только для чтения. Скоро вернёмся к нормальному режиму работы. Visit [our status page](https://www.stackstatus.net) or search [our recent meta posts on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+site-maintenance?tab=Newest) for more info.

[image: скриншот]